# How do I resolve this error : "The provided double value is non-finite"?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm developing a music web app and i want to add a volume adjust feature to it. My code :

```
const audioPlayer = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(audioPlayer){
      audioPlayer.current.volume = volume/100;
    }
  },[volume])

        <input
          className="progress-bar progress-bar-2 hidden md:block"
          type="range"
          defaultValue={0}
          min={0}
          max={100}
          value={volume}
          onChange={(e,v) => setVolume(v)}
        />
```

I did everything right but when the function inside onChange runs I get this error

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
    at input
    at div
    at div
    at AudioPlayer (http://localhost:5173/src/components/audioPlayer.jsx:34:7)
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx:28:47)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.
    at audioPlayer.jsx:103:27
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:9)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:7)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26935:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
```

How do i resolve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue *may* be that the onChange event in your code does not pass the value of the input element to the setVolume function. Instead, it passes the event object, which has a target property that contains the value of the input element. You can try updating the onChange event handler to pass the target property of the event object to the setVolume function, like this:

```
<input
  className="progress-bar progress-bar-2 hidden md:block"
  type="range"
  defaultValue={0}
  min={0}
  max={100}
  value={volume}
  onChange={(e) => setVolume(e.target.value)}
/>
```